# Can a maven profile activation be based on a property substring?

Tags: maven, jenkins

Is there any way to use a substring of a property for profile activation in Maven?  I'm looking to use Jenkins to simply pass the branch name to my build, and have a profile activated if it is a release/* branch.

Is there any way I can do parameter manipulation like this for profile activation?  Ex:

```
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      <id>appserverConfig-dev</id>
      <activation>
        <property>
          <name>branch</name>

          <!-- some form of wildcarding or regex on the parameter value ??? -->
          <value>release/.*</value>   
        </property>
      </activation>
      <properties>
        <appserver.home>/path/to/dev/appserver</appserver.home>
      </properties>
    </profile>
   </profiles>
```

Or is there a better approach that I can use to only activate the profile if the build is coming from a release branch?

Comment: maybe with http://www.mojohaus.org/build-helper-maven-plugin/regex-property-mojo.html

Comment: @eduyayo unfortunately I don't believe so.  Profile activation is done prior to any plugins being run, so I can't rely on a plugin to do it.

Comment: You can run it in verify phase